# Simplify oversimplifies. What to do about it?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

According to Mathematica 10: $$\mbox{Simplify}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{t^2}-1}{(t+\frac{1}{t})^2}\right]==\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

However, the first equation does not tolerate $t=0$ because of a division by zero, but the second equation cleary does allow $t=0$.

How come and what can I do to avoid this?

**Raw input:**

```
f[t_] = (1/t^2 - 1)/(t + 1/t)^2
FunctionDomain[f[t], t]
g[t_] = Simplify[f[t]]
FunctionDomain[g[t], t]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The singularity of the first expression is removable at $t=0$, taking value $1$. Unless you're really nitpicking, the simplification is everywhere correct, and it's only incorrect in the sense that a removable singularity has been removed.

Comment: You'll find this sort of limitation in pretty much every computer algebra system.  First check `FunctionDomain` for a potential workaround, then [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/why-does-mathematica-simplify-x-x-to1/) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65624/a-one-line-proof-that-one-is-zero-using-mathematica-10/).  I would consider this a duplicate of these question (there are more on the same topic).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how well this works for more complicated expressions, but my idea is as follows:

Using the option `ComplexityFunction`. If the domain of an intermediate expression is larger than the original expression, assign a very large penalty. Add this to Mathematica's default complexity function (`` Simplify`SimplifyCount ``).

```
(* define domain for readability *)
domain[e_, x_] := FunctionDomain[e, x, Complexes, Method -> {"Reduced" -> False}]

CarefulSimplify[expr_, x_, r___] := With[{dom = domain[expr, x]},
  Simplify[expr, r, 
    ComplexityFunction -> (Simplify`SimplifyCount[#] + 
      10^20 Boole[!TrueQ[PossibleZeroQ[expr - #] && 
        Reduce[Equivalent[dom, domain[#, x]]]]]&)
  ]
]
```

For your example this works, but again I haven't tried this for more complicated expressions.

```
CarefulSimplify[(1/t^2 - 1)/(t + 1/t)^2, t]
```

> ```
> (-1 + 1/t^2)/(1/t + t)^2
> ```

**Edit:** I've incorporated Karsten 7.'s idea, since otherwise we're calling `Reduce` more than we need to.

Comment: Or one might use `Method -> {"Reduced" -> False}` instead of `Complexes` or no third argument.