# Mystery Constant of Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Upon evaluating the integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^(2 n)] x^(2 k), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    Assumptions -> {n > 0, k > 0, (n | k) \[Element] Integers}]
```

I get the result (`$Version`=`"11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"`)

```
ConditionalExpression[
    (((-1)^(2 n))^(-((1 + 2 k)/(2 n))) ((-1)^(2 k) + ((-1)^(2 n))^((1 + 2 k)/(2 n))) 
    Gamma[(1 + 2 k)/(2 n)])/(2 n), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
    n < 1/4 + C[1] && C[1] >= 1 && C[1] < 1/4 + n]
```

My question is: what is `C[1]` doing there?  It's a definite integral, so there should be no constant of integration.  Moreover, it doesn't show up in the "value" part of the `ConditionalExpression`.  Putting the inequalities with `n` together just gives `n < 1/2 + n`, which is always true, so I think the only thing that it enforces is that (saturating the bound on `C[1]`), `1 ≤ 1/4 + n` so that `n` must be at least 1 (if it's going to be an integer).  But I already told Mma that it's a positive integer, so in the end those conditionals should all be satisfied.  So: **what's the point of `C[1]` in this result?**

As an added (but not super-important) follow-up, if I tell Mma that `n` and `k` are integers, why doesn't it simplify `(-1)^(2 k)` or the other squares of -1?

## Update as of Version 13.0

As of `$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"` the result I get is

```
(((-1)^(2 n))^(-((1+2 k)/(2 n))) ((-1)^(2 k)+((-1)^(2 n))^((1+2 k)/(2 n))) Gamma[(1+2 k)/(2 n)])/(2 n)
```

which, at least, has eliminated the unneeded mystery constant.  Of course, it's still not leveraging all of the assumptions, since

```
FullSimplify[%, 
    Assumptions -> {n > 0, k > 0, (n | k) \[Element] Integers}]
```

yields `Gamma[(1+2 k)/(2 n)]/n`.

So, why doesn't `Integrate` *actually* leverage the assumptions?

Comment: the `C[1]` is not an integration constant, it is part of the conditional on `n`

Comment: Why is there an arbitrary constant introduced in order to formulate a conditional on `n` that's redundant with what I already specified?

Comment: IDK. It is redundant, it says `n` must be +/- 1/4 of an integer >=1 , ie true for all integers > 0.   FWIW v10.1 just gives the (unsimplified) expression, not conditional.

Comment: So, what's the point of C[1] in the result?  Also it doesn't say n must be ±1/4 of an integer, since C[1] need not be an integer.

Comment: If it's changed since v10.1, that's also a mystery!

Comment: Version 12.3.1 on Widows 10 answers $$ \frac{\left((-1)^{2 n}\right)^{-\frac{2 k+1}{2 n}} \left(\left((-1)^{2 n}\right)^{\frac{2 k+1}{2 n}}+(-1)^{2 k}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2 k+1}{2 n}\right)}{2 n}.$$

Comment: Aha, so this one has been fixed for a while! (Though still no recognition that given the `Assumptions`, `(-1)^2n = 1` (for example).)

Comment: In addition,  `Integrate[Exp[-x^(2 n)] x^(2 k), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {n > 0, k > 0}]` produces the same result.

Answer (score 8):

In:

```
Assuming[{n > 0 && k > 0 && {n, k} \[Element] Integers}, 
 Integrate[Exp[-x^(2 n)] x^(2 k), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If anyone is interested in it, you can check the implemention.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Integrate]
PrintDefinitions[Assuming]
```

Comment: I get the same result, using `Assuming` rather than `Assumptions->`.  Why the difference?

Comment: `Assuming` seems to apply an extra simplify step.

Comment: I alway prefer Assuming. I guess Assumptions failed me many times. Integrate always ask Assumptions to shut it up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/22OdB.png

Comment: What `Integrate` does with `Assumptions` is, in my opinion, far the safer handling in general.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the `C[1]` comes from this:

```
Reduce[k > 0 && n > 0 && Re[(-1)^(1 + 2 n)] < 0, Complexes]
Simplify[%, (k | n) ∈ Integers && k >= 1 && n >= 1]
(*
  C[1] ∈ Integers && 
    k > 0 && (0 < n < 1/4 || (C[1] >= 1 && 1/4 (-1 + 4 C[1]) < n < 1/4 (1 + 4 C[1])))
  C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 1 && C[1] < 1/4 + n && n < 1/4 + C[1]
*)
```

One can get the `Reduce` commands used in `Integrate[]` with this:

```
Trace[
 Integrate[Exp[-x^(2 n)] x^(2 k), {x, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {n > 0, k > 0, (n | k) ∈ Integers}],
 _Reduce,
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

It's hard to say exactly what `Reduce` is being used for beyond the easy guess that it has something to do with convergence.

The follow-up question about simplifying `(-1)^(2 k)` is a key to another workaround:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^(2 n)] x^(2 k), {x, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> {n > 0, k > 0, (n | k) ∈ Integers, (-1)^(2 k) == 1, (-1)^(2 n) == 1}]
(*  Gamma[(1 + 2 k)/(2 n)]/(2 n)  *)
```

And *Mathematica* can simplify `(-1)^(2k)`:

```
Simplify[{(1)^(2 k), (-1)^(1 + 2 k)}, k ∈ Integers]
(*  {1, -1}  *)
```

`Simplify` uses the assumptions from [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), which
are added to by [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html);
it is probably why 
[@UnchartedWorks's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43670/unchartedworks) workaround works, and perhaps why [@Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) warns against it.

Some related Q&A:

[Usage of Assuming for Integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration)

[Solution to a specific problem caused by generic simplification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126272/solution-to-a-specific-problem-caused-by-generic-simplification)

[Simplify is excluding indeterminate expression from output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144899/simplify-is-excluding-indeterminate-expression-from-output)

[What is a "generic case"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124347/what-is-a-generic-case)